# How to create own commands for the terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, command-line

my question is the one which is written in the title.

I installed a program (Teamspeak 3 Client) on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Clientversion System. Now I would like to start it in the terminal with the command **"teamspeak3"**. 
The program is installed in *"/opt/teamspeak3/"* and I am new on Linux.

**So how to create such a command?**

So it would be really nice, if someone could help me :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your wider question:

- Create a new file in `~/bin/` (create it if it doesn't exist).
- Write your script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # do something here.
  ```
- Give that file executable permissions:

  ```
  chmod +x ~/bin/filename
  ```

In your particular case you could:

- Symlink the executable into `/usr/bin/`:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /opt/teamspeak3/teamspeak3 /usr/bin/
  ```

  This won't always work. Some things behave strangely when symlinked and some things need to be run from the right path... But it's simple and it might work.
- Or, you could write a little script (as above) but in `/usr/bin/` instead of `~/bin/` (you'll need to prepend the commands with `sudo`)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that symbolix link in /usr/bin solved my problem! --> Thumbs up!